# Serializer + Rails.application.routes.default_url_options + Multiple Domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined a serializer consisting of

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

which compel me to define the host in config files as:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options =
    config.action_controller.default_url_options =
    config.default_url_options =
  {
    protocol: 'https'
    host: ENV.fetch('HOSTNAME')
  }
```

But I do not want to use hostname config variable as in hostname only one doman can be defined, but my application uses multple domains. Hence defining a single domain restricts me to use that particular domain only.

Comment: I see this article now http://excid3.com/blog/change-actionmailer-email-url-host-dynamically
 try do the same thing for default_url_options

best Implementation here https://makandracards.com/makandra/1353-make-actionmailer-use-the-current-request-host-and-protocol-for-url-generation